# Create journals with Suitescript and pass Parameters

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I am wanting to create a journal transaction with set parameters in the url.

In particular, [image: url], the part of the url in the pink box needs to be constant for each journal that is created

For the 'id=22126' part, this will be variable and will be based on an array from created from a saved search.

Is it possible to do this?

What modules would I be looking at in Suitescript?

I haven't really written much script (just trying to learn) so I am not really sure where to begin with this

An additional screenshot showing what is in the journal when those parameters are entered
[image: journal]

Comment: Are you trying to create JEs or void them?  Because if creating a JE you would not need an id.  Ids only exist after the JE is created.  Are you trying to run a saved search and have the system call the url above per each search result found?

Comment: I am trying to create a journal entry that is a void of an existing journal.

From what I can see, you need to have the original journal's id in the url before you can create a void journal

Comment: Take a look at the N/transaction module, specifically transaction.void()

Comment: Thanks Victor. I had a look though this particular record type (journal created from time entry) wasn't part of the list of supported record types